# Populating a spinner in an alert dialog

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-spinner, android-alertdialog, android-dialogfragment

I have a class that extends a dialogFragment within my main activity. The purpose of this class is to bring up a dialog with a spinner and edit text, and then return those strings to the main activity. I am having a problem populating my spinner. The spinner is supposed to display a list of available wifi networks, but instead, it does not show anything.

So my question is, how can I use my broadcast receiver class to populate a spinner once it is needed in the alert dialog?
Thanks for any help, here is the code that I currently have...

**Edit**

I have done some error checking in my program, and it seems that the broadcast receiver is never called from within the dialog fragment, how can I get the broadcast receiver that is in the dialog fragment to run?

```
public static class MyAlertDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    Spinner sp;
    WifiManager mainWifiObj;
    WifiScanReceiver wifiReciever;
    ListView list;

    String wifis[];
    EditText nameANick;
    public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs";
    public static final String Name = "nameKey";
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;

    public static MyAlertDialogFragment newInstance(String title) {
        MyAlertDialogFragment frag = new MyAlertDialogFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("title", title);
        frag.setArguments(args);
        return frag;
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.i("Dialog", "OnCreate");

        sharedpreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        mainWifiObj = (WifiManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        wifiReciever = new WifiScanReceiver();
        mainWifiObj.startScan();
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        getActivity().unregisterReceiver(wifiReciever);
        super.onDestroy();

    }

    class WifiScanReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @SuppressLint("UseValueOf")
        public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {
            List<ScanResult> wifiScanList = mainWifiObj.getScanResults();
            wifis = new String[wifiScanList.size()];
            int j = 0;

            if (sharedpreferences.contains(Name)) {
                wifis[0] = sharedpreferences.getString(Name, "");
                for (int i = 1; i < wifiScanList.size(); i++) {
                    wifis[i] = ((wifiScanList.get(j).SSID));
                    j++;
                }
            } else {
                for (int i = 0; i < wifiScanList.size(); i++) {
                    wifis[i] = ((wifiScanList.get(j).SSID));
                    j++;
                }

            }
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                    wifis);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            sp.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }

    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
        LinearLayout root = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.my_dialog, null);

        nameANick = (EditText) root.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        sp = (Spinner) root.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);


        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setTitle("Set Nickname1")
                .setView(root)
                .setPositiveButton("Save",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,

                                ((MainActivity) getActivity())
                                        .doPositiveClick();
                            }
                        })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int whichButton) {
                                ((MainActivity) getActivity())
                                        .doNegativeClick();
                            }
                        }).create();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reordered the logic of the program and now it works. Instead of declaring the broadcast receiver inside the alert dialog class, call it with the onCreate of the main activity. This way, you can pass a string array to the dialog fragment and then populate the spinner with that.